# Local Supersymmetry and Space-time Metric

Tags: metric-tensor, supersymmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, supergravity

So following from [*Simple Supergravity*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.10044) (arxiv:2212.10044), on page 5, it's written that

> Only the spacetime metric can couple to the energy-momentum tensor...

Can anyone explain why it must be the spacetime metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ and not any rank-2 tensor $A_{\mu\nu}$?